# Вызвать функцию с динамическим названием

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется сервис, который включает в себя несколько функций, возвращающих данные с сервера. Причем для одной модели данных имеется 2 метода: один возвращает данные, которые сохранились локально, второй - делает запрос на сервер и обновляет локальные данные. Существует проверка, которая определяет, возвращать локальные данные или тянуть их из сервера.

Проблема в том, что во всех методах имеется дублирующийся код. Я решил вынести все это дело в отдельный метод. И столкнулся с проблемой динамического вызова функции. Сейчас вы все поймете :)

```js
(function() {
  
  exampleService.$inject = ['exmplResource']
  
  function exampleService(exmplResource) {
    // Тут просто храним данные, ничего такого.
    const localObj = {
      passwords: [],
      statistic: {},
      userId: null
    };
    
    // Здесь наша API сервиса. 
    return {
      getPasswords,
      updatePasswordsFromServer,
      getStatistic,
      updateStatisticFromServer
    };
    
    /* Дальше будет 4 метода, они очень похожи. Вопрос, который меня 
       интересует, находится в методе getData
     */
    
    // Функция, которая должна вернуть все пароли для определенного пользователя
    function getPasswords(userId)
      getData('passwords', userId);
    }
    
    // Ходит на сервер за данными и обновляет их локально.
    function updatePasswordsFromServer(userId) {
      return exmplResource
        .getPasswords(userId)
        .then(onSuccess);
        
      function onSuccess(newPasswords) {
        localObj.passwords.splice(0, localObj.passwords.length);
        localObj.passwords.push(...newPasswords);
        
        localObj.userId = userId;
        
        return newPasswords;
      }
    }
    
    // Такая же фигня, что и с паролями :)
    function getStatistic(userId)
      getData('statistic', userId);
    }
    
    // Тоже сгоняли на сервак и локально обновились.
    function updateStatisticFromServer(userId) {
      return exmplResource
        .getStatistic(userId)
        .then(onSuccess);
        
      function onSuccess(newStatistic) {
        Object.assign(localObj.statistic, newStatistic);
        
        localObj.userId = userId;
        
        return newStatistic;
      }
    }
    
    /* !!!!!!!!!!!! Вот это чудо, которое я пытаюсь сотворить :) 
       Смотрим, если данные для этого пользователя есть локально, тогда сразу
       отдаем ему их. Если нет, вызываем методы, которые у нас есть для 
       обновления локальных данных.
    */
    function getData(field, userId) {
      function onPromise(resolve) {
        // Если пользовальтель тот же, то у нас уже есть нужные ему пароли
        if (localObj.userId === userId) {
          resolve(localObj[field]);
        } else {
          /* вот тут нужно вызвать как-то нужный нам метод на основе
            "field". 
            window[`update${field}FromServer`](userId) ???
              .then(newData => resolve(newData));
          */
        }
      }
      
      return new Promise(onPromise);
    }
  }
  
  angular
    .module('testModule')
    .service('exampleService', exampleService); 
})();
```

Пока писал вопрос, подумал, может не нужно отдельно методы на update выделять? Просто сделать как-то так

```js
function getData(field, userId) {
  function onPromise(resolve) {
    // Если пользовальтель тот же, то у нас уже есть нужные ему пароли
    if (localObj.userId === userId) {
      resolve(localObj[field]);
    } else {
      exmplResource[`update${field}FromServer`][`get${field}`]
        .then(newData => resolve(newData);
    }
  }

  return new Promise(onPromise);
}
```

Но это читерство. Проблему в первом случае я так и не понял, как решать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как тут правильнее поступить.

Был бы очень признателен, как дополнение к вопросу, если опытные люди сказали бы, нужно ли вообще вот так изощрятся и динамечески генерить методы. Читабельность пропадает, но зато не дублируется код. Чем здесь лучше пожертвовать? И, может, по коду есть замечания? Хочется научиться писать нормально кодяру, чтобы другие люди могли ее прочитать. Спасибо! :)

Comment: зачем нужен if в getData, если можно просто продолжить цепочку в нужном методе: `getData('passwords', userId).then(updatePasswordsFromServer)`. Или данные как-то по другому связаны?

Comment: @Grundy так я ведь не всегда хочу делать update. Если данные для userId уже когда-то тянулись с сервера и сохранились, то я их сразу отдам, без дополнительного запроса на сервер.

Comment: _"Но это читерство."_ - вовсе нет! Это вполне стандартный способ обращения к полям объекта... несмотря на то что SO такой код не любит и в ответах - рьяно минусует (проверено `:D`).

Comment: Конечно же, надо сделать оговорку что подобный синтаксис требует очень четкого понимания алгоритма, и предусмотрительности (т.к. при неосторожном обращении, потенциальных ошибок может быть масса).

Comment: Зачем вам `new Promise` когда вы можете вернуть результат вызова?

Comment: @PavelMayorov для универсальности метода. Обратите внимание, в одном случае я возвращаю обычные сохраненные данные, а в другом - промис. Т.е. в контроллере нужно будет проверять, что вернулось: просто данные или промис. Если данные, то просто их присвоить в переменную, а если промис, то вызывать колбэк, в котором присваивать данные переменной. А так, я всегда возвращаю промис и в контроллере не нужно делать никаких проверок.

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko обратите внимание на метод Promise.resolve

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, я Вас понял. Это будет более уместно. Круто! Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать следующим образом.

Поскольку функции `updatePasswordsFromServer` и `updateStatisticFromServer` выполняют одно и то же действие, то можно их объединить в одну функцию. Поскольку в них различна только функция, которая вызывается для получения данных, то можно передать эту функцию в параметрах.

Например так:

```js
(function() {

  exampleService.$inject = ['exmplResource']

  function exampleService(exmplResource) {
    // Тут просто храним данные, ничего такого.
    const localObj = {
      passwords: [],
      statistic: {},
      userId: null
    };

    // Создаем параметры для запроса     
    const params = {
      passwords: {
        field: 'passwords',
        method: 'getPasswords'
      },
      statistic: {
        field: 'statistic',
        method: 'getStatistic'
      }
    };

    // Здесь наша API сервиса. 
    return {
      getPasswords,
      updatePasswordsFromServer,
      getStatistic,
      updateStatisticFromServer
    };


    // Функция, которая должна вернуть все пароли для определенного пользователя
    function getPasswords(userId) {
      return getData(params.passwords, userId);
    }

    // Такая же фигня, что и с паролями :)
    function getStatistic(userId) {
      return getData(params.statistic, userId);
    }

    // Ходит на сервер за данными.
    function update(userId, func) {
      return exmplResource[func](userId);
    }


    /* !!!!!!!!!!!! Вот это чудо, которое я пытаюсь сотворить :) 
       Смотрим, если данные для этого пользователя есть локально, тогда сразу
       отдаем ему их. Если нет, вызываем методы, которые у нас есть для 
       обновления локальных данных.
    */
    function getData(param, userId) {
      function onPromise(resolve) {
        // Если пользовальтель тот же, то у нас уже есть нужные ему пароли
        if (localObj.userId === userId) {
          resolve(localObj[param.field]);
        } else {
          update(userId, param.method).then(function(result) {
            localObj[param.field] = result;
            localObj.userId = userId;
            resolve(localObj[param.field]);
          });
        }
      }

      return new Promise(onPromise);
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('testModule')
    .service('exampleService', exampleService);
})();
```

Comment: Очень хороший и элегантный вариант, спасибо! :)

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko Если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный.